# How to change background in button with command, inside a class python tkinter OOP?

Tags: python, tkinter

**Welcome**
I want to make board like in the chess. After I click this button should change your background with method 'command'. I tried put in my code StringVar(), .config, global variable and lambda. If there is a link to solve this I'll be glad. (This is my first question on this site and sorry for everything)

```
from tkinter import *

class App():
    """docstring for App"""
    root=Tk(className="application 4")
    x, y = 0, 0
    tab = []

    def __init__(self, x, y):
        App.x = x
        App.y = y
        App.root.geometry("800x600")
        App.root.resizable(height = FALSE, width = FALSE)
        for i in range(App.x):
            for j in range(App.y):
                App.tab.append(Button(App.root, width=1, bg="white", command=lambda: self.changeBG(self)).grid(row=i, column=j))
        App.root.mainloop()


    def changeBG(self, btn):
        self.config(bg = "red")


application = App(10, 10)
```

**Error:**

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\S\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1883, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "C:\Users\S\Desktop\Spanish number project\clicked.py", line 16, in <lambda>
    App.tab.append(Button(App.root, width=1, bg="white", command=lambda: self.changeBG(self)).grid(row=i, column=j))
  File "C:\Users\S\Desktop\Spanish number project\clicked.py", line 21, in changeBG
    self.config(bg = "red")
AttributeError: 'App' object has no attribute 'config'
[Finished in 6.4s]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have never used the `tkinter` module before though I have been wanting to learn.

So this is an attempt to debug your code. DISCLAIMER: This code runs as expected. I have no idea if it follows the conventions for creating apps with `tkinter`. I used the example code in the question as a guide.

A clue to the problem is in the exception: `changeBG self.config(bg = "red") AttributeError: 'App' object has no attribute 'config'`

My first guess was that buttons must have attribute you are trying to modify and not the `App` class instance that `self` names.

I created a matrix (2D list or "list of lists") in which the buttons can be stored.

Note that your code creates a `Button` instance and then calls the `grid` method on the button without ever storing the button instance in a name. The return of that `grid` method is `None`. The `self.tab` in your original code was a list of `None`s. In my code I called `grid` on the button after it was instantiated.

I used this answer to figure out how to pass arguments to a command callback since no arguments are implicitly passed:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/35780253/1913726

The values of `row` and `col` are captured in the lambda. When the button is clicked the instance method `changeBG` is called in the lambda with the proper arguments, the button is retrieved from the matrix, and the background color is updated.

I made some edits in your class.

```
from tkinter import *


class App:

    root = Tk(className="application 4")
    root.geometry("800x600")
    root.resizable(height=FALSE, width=FALSE)

    def __init__(self, x, y):
        # create a matrix for the buttons
        self.tab = [[None] * y for _ in range(x)]
        for row in range(x):
            for col in range(y):
                button = Button(
                    self.root,
                    width=1,
                    bg="white",
                    # use keyword arguments to pass values into instance method
                    command=lambda row=row, col=col: self.changeBG(row, col),
                )
                # place the button on a grid after instantiation
                # The return of `grid` is None
                button.grid(row=row, column=col)
                # assign the value in the matrix to the button
                self.tab[row][col] = button
        self.root.mainloop()

    def changeBG(self, row, col):
        # the button has the attribute "config"
        button = self.tab[row][col]  # get button from matrix
        button.config(bg="red")
        print(f"You clicked button '{button}' at row {row} and col {col}")


application = App(10, 10)
```

Comment: You’re welcome. I learned a lot from helping you answer this.